# Why does the following swift code gives error?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

The array does not append with a custom class object

```
// Create an array with String and Double
var shoppingList = ["Eggs", 2.0]

// Append array with string object
shoppingList += ["Milk"]

// Declare an example class 
    class Foo  {
        var name : String?
        func Foo() {
            name = "Default Name"
        }
}


var foo : Foo = Foo()
shoppingList += [foo] // Error : '[NSObject]' is not identical to 'Uint8'
```

Why would shoppingList not append foo object?

Comment: What error does the compiler give?

Comment: Its written in the last line.

// Error : '[NSObject]' is not identical to 'Uint8'

Comment: You can't add a class `Foo` to the `shoppingList` array.

Comment: Why is what I am trying to understand. There is no explicit type declared as I was able to add String Type and Int Type.

Why would it try to compare the new appended object with Uint8?

Comment: You got an upvote from me - just because it's a simple question doesn't make it a bad one. That compiler error doesn't help at all, and to a beginner, it's probably not readily apparent that arrays can have automatically-inferred generic type parameters.

Comment: Thanks. It would have been better if everyone could share that perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift error messages are frequently very cryptic.  I'm not sure what the `Uint8` is all about.

Swift arrays hold a single type.  In this case, your `shoppingList` has been inferred to be of type `[NSObject]` since Swift is able to bridge `"Eggs"` to `NSString` and `2.0` to `NSNumber`.  Both `NSString` and `NSNumber` are subclasses of `NSObject`, so Swift infers your array to be of type `[NSObject]`.

If you want to put `Foo()` into that array, then `Foo` will also need to be a subclass of `NSObject`:

```
class Foo: NSObject { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for crystal clear explanation. I tried that and now it makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @vacawama's solution, you can explicitly specify the array element type rather than letting type inference set it for you:

```
var shoppingList: [AnyObject] = ["Eggs", 2.0]
```

The clear advantage of having the value type set to `AnyObject` is that you don't have to make custom classes inherit from `NSObject`